# Split data clumped in one variable to multiple variables in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I'm a bit new to R so excuse me if I'm not using the right lingo.
I'm trying to tidy a data frame that has one variable clumping data that I want to split up into different variables. Essentially, it looks like this:

```
ID    Scores

01    Math: 5, Physics: 4, English: 3  
02    English: 5, Math: 3, Physics: 6.9  
03    Math: 3.75, Chemistry: 4, English: 3  
04    History: 8, Math: 2, Physics: 3
```

I want it to look like this:

```
ID    Math     Chemistry    English     History     Physics         

01    5        NaN          3           NaN         4
02    3        NaN          5           NaN         6.9
03    3.75     4            3           NaN         NaN
04    2        NaN          NaN         8           3
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a `tidyverse` approach with some `tidyr` functions. You can separate your variable `Scores` first at row level and then at column level. Finally, you can reshape to obtain the desired output. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Scores = c("Math: 5, Physics: 4, English: 3", 
"English: 5, Math: 3, Physics: 6.9", "Math: 3.75, Chemistry: 4, English: 3", 
"History: 8, Math: 2, Physics: 3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

The code:

```
#Code
df %>% separate_rows(Scores,sep = ',') %>%
  #Format
  mutate(Scores=trimws(Scores)) %>%
  #Separate again by :
  separate(Scores,sep=':',into = c('Subject','Grade')) %>%
  #Format
  mutate(Subject=trimws(Subject),Grade=as.numeric(trimws(Grade))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Subject,values_from=Grade)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
     ID  Math Physics English Chemistry History
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1  5        4         3        NA      NA
2     2  3        6.9       5        NA      NA
3     3  3.75    NA         3         4      NA
4     4  2        3        NA        NA       8
```